# Will everything in the standard library treat strings as unicode in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, unicode, string, cgi, python-3.x

I'm a little confused about how the standard library will behave now that Python (from 3.0) is unicode-based. Will modules such as CGI and urllib use unicode strings or will they use the new 'bytes' type and just provide encoded data?

Comment: Perhaps this question should not be answered by fellow programmers, but by the Python developers (indirectly, preferably; browse the developer's discussions here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/ )

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Logically a lot of things like MIME-encoded mail messages, URLs, XML documents, and so on should be returned as `bytes` not strings. This could cause some consternation as the libraries start to be nailed down for Python 3 and people discover that they have to be more aware of the `bytes`/`string` conversions than they were for `str`/`unicode` ...

Answer (score 7):

One of the great things about this question (and Python in general) is that you can just mess around in the interpreter! [Python 3.0 rc1 is currently available for download](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/).

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> fh = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
>>> print(type(fh.read(100)))
<class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: I agree - I compiled and installed rc1 earlier this morning, I've spent too much of my day playing around with it already! I was just wondering if there was a standard rule for what will be unicode and what isn't.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a two-step dance here.  See [Python 3000 and You](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=227041).

Step 1 is to get running under 3.0.

Step 2 is to rethink your API's to, perhaps, do something more sensible.

The most likely course is that the libraries will switch to unicode strings to remain as compatible as possible with how they used to work.

Then, perhaps, some will switch to bytes to more properly implement the RFC standards for the various protocols.